# Webpack and Angular Error Cannot read property 'setGlobalVar'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

When running the UI of my program, the developer tools is giving me the error `Cannot read property 'setGlobalVar' of null ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setGlobalVar' of null.`

My webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        polyfills: './app/polyfills.ts',
        app: './app/main.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            //Order of loaders is important!
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: ['node_modules'],
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' },{ loader: 'ts-loader' }, { loader: 'angular-router-loader' }, { loader: 'angular2-template-loader' }],
            },
            {
                test: /\.sass$/,
                exclude: ['node_modules'],
                use: [{ loader: 'css-to-string-loader' }, { loader: 'raw-loader' }, { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, sourceMapContents: true } }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: ['node_modules'],
                use: [{ loader: 'css-to-string-loader' }, { loader: 'raw-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: ['node_modules', 'index.html'],
                use: [{ loader: 'raw-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(otf|eot|svg|png|ttf|woff|woff2).*$/,
                exclude: ['node_modules'],
                use: [{ loader: 'url-loader' }]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.css'],
        modules: ["node_modules", "."]
    },
    plugins: [

      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          names: ['vendor'],
          minChunks: function (module, count) {
              // creates a common vendor js file for libraries in node_modules
              return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
          }
      }),

      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
          names: ['meta'],
          chunks: ['vendor', 'app']
      }),

      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: 'index.cshtml',
          filename: 'index.cshtml',
          inject: 'head'
          , chunks: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills', 'meta']
          , chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
          , hash: false
      }),

      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, //Update for Angular 4
        root('./app'),
        {}
      ),
    ]
};
function root(__path) {
    return path.join(__dirname, __path);
}
```

I am using Angular 4.1.0 and this issue error only came up after the update from Angular 2 to Angular 4. There is very minimal support for this issue in doing a google search so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, the issue has nothing to do with your Webpack configuration.

To get past the error, comment or remove the `disableDebugTools()` call from your environment config file, normally the `environment.ts` file.